# iOS icons are all blurry even after @2x copies are made

Tags: ios, user-interface, icons, retina-display

I have had my designer create all of the icons for an app and they are all blurry. At first, I doubted the designer, but we ended up getting a little icon kit from an extremely well known iOS app designer. I implemented them, and I got the same blurriness as before.

So I know it's not my designer. It has to be my (the coder) fault somehow. I once saw something about getting a CGRefContext or something to make icons and images sharper, but I can no longer find the SO question where somebody said that answer :(

I have saved a regular sized icon + a @2x sized icon of everything in the app.

For example, we're trying to put in some toolbar icons into a toolbar, and the images are sized at 25 x 25 for the normal size, and then 50 x 50 in the @2x size.

Also, I am testing directly to an iPhone 4S. So it's not like I'm viewing it in the Simulator or something.

I have looked up the icon sizes guidelines, and to make the icon sizes all double would just result in a much larger version of the icons. Perhaps there is some way to shrink them programmatically that I'm unaware of?

Please help. We've been passively trying to correct this problem for weeks!

**Icons on Request:**

normal
[image: guestlist_icon.png]

@2x
[image: guestlist_icon@2x.png]

Comment: Please attach the images to the question, and tell us how you are assigning them (e.g. via storyboards / xibs or in code, show the code if the latter).

Comment: Basically, if you have the right images, it just works. You don't need to do anything special. So either you've made the images wrong, or you're using them wrong.

Comment: I added an example icon in an edit. These are supposed to go inside of a `UIToolBar`. Also, I'm just calling them out in the storyboard. I'm adding a `UIButton` into the tool bar, changing the style of the button to plain, and then setting the image to this icon.

Comment: I feel like it's a naming error. What are the file names of your icons?

Comment: I can't imagine how that could be. normal sized one is named "guestlist_icon.png", while the 2x one is named, "guestlist_icon@2x.png"

Comment: One of the the first things to check when this happens is the origin of the view. If it's placed at a coordinate thats not a whole number, the texture will look blurry. For example an origin of (10.5, 10.5) will produce a blurry image, while an origin of (10.0, 10.0) will not. It's something to do with the image landing on half pixels, which the screen can't draw. Check the origin of the superview too.

Comment: How are you loading the image? Is it in code? If so can you show the code? Is it in IB? If so you can't load images like this in IB, it has to be in code.

Comment: @jsksma2 - you mentioned you are adding a `UIButton` to the toolbar.  Any reason you are not just adding a `UIBarButtonItem` to the toolbar?  Also, when you say "blurry", it's hard to gauge what that means.  I've loaded your images on a toolbar, and it does not look blurry to me. Would be helpful to see a screen shot of the toolbar with the blurry icons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I asked this 6 months ago, I hope this question can still help some in the future. I have learned that the best way to get the sharpest images possible starts with the designer.

The designer needs to be using a vector-based application such as Adobe Illustrator when finalizing designs. They should NOT be finalizing designs with pixel-based applications like Adobe Photoshop.

This did not turn out to be my problem when I asked this question. It was actually my idiotic fault. I had saved the images as @2X instead of @2x. So the retina images were never being loaded. Seriously one the biggest Homer Simpson "Doh!" moments in my life.

Answer (score 0):

Before all, I don't understand which that means: "Also, I am testing directly to an iPhone 4S. So it's not like I'm viewing it in the Simulator or something."

The problem possible:

1. The nomination of the image -> According to your comment, I think the nomination is right.
2. The way you create image -> If you use method like "imageNamed", it will take care of the 2x image. If you use method like "imageWithContentsOfFile", you need to do it yourself:

   ```
   -(NSString *)getPathByFileName:(NSString *)name{
       if([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0) {
           return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[name stringByAppendingString:@"@2x"] ofType:@"jpg"];
       }else{
           return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"jpg"];
       }
   }
   [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self getPathByFileName:name]];
   ```
3. You sure all files added in Xcode.

Comment: Yes. All of that is either common sense, or doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is it the same problem between simulator and device?

Comment: No, If I pull the icons up on retina 4 inch on the Simulator, they look great. But I didn't want to depend on a computer screen.